# Meteor & Iron: Using tag from array as path

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I'm using Iron Router for Meteor and I have these routes set up and working so far:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('home', {
        path: '/',
        template: 'home'
    });

    this.route('userProfile', {
        path: '/user/:username',
        data: function () {
            return Meteor.users.findOne({username: this.params.username})},
        template: 'userProfile'
    });

    this.route('postPage', {
        path: '/post/:_id',
        data: function () {
            return Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id})},
        template: 'postPage'
    });

    this.route('settings', {
        path: '/settings',
        template: 'settings'
    });
});
```

I'd like to introduce another route that would take you to a page where posts are organised by tag. For example `http://foo.bar/tag/mexican` would take you to a page displaying all the posts that have the tag `mexican` in an array. The posts are stored in the collection like so:

```
{
    "_id" : "G6xrPYedPzG8KGBTF",
    "title" : "Chilli Con Carne",
    "rating" : 4,
    "tags" : [  "kidneybeans",  "mexican",  "rice" ],
    "description" : "A meaty mexican dish with rice.",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-02-15T23:45:12.384Z"),
    "owner" : "vh7DjWM9NwbkGSNg9",
    "username" : "snowingjack"
}
```

I've been able to make routes that pass data by post._id as you can see, but now I can't figure out how to make a route where `/tag/:tag` would take me to page with the data is the `posts` collection queried by tag. I'm fine running a query that will just return posts with a certain tag like `return Posts.find({tags: "mexican"});` but I'm struggling with how to pass all this data around to get the desired effect.

**Ideas?**

P.S. I also have a template I use to spit out tags in a sane fashion with hashtags and spaces and links and whatnot. I'd love to be able to find a solution where this would work:

```
<template name="tagListItem">
    <span class="tag-list__item"><a href="{{pathFor 'tagPage'}}">#{{this}}</a></span>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the route would look something like this:

```
this.route('tagPage', {
    path: '/tags/:tag',
    data: function () {
        return Posts.find({tags: this.params.tag)},
    template: 'tagPage'
});
```

And the anchor tag inside the template you use to output tag links would probably look like this ( though I'm not exactly sure the data context of the template you mentioned in your post):

```
<a href="/tags/{{this}}">#{{this}}</a>
```

The other thing you would have to consider is how you are publishing and subscribing to posts. You might want to make a separate pub/sub relationship for tags so you are sending posts with tags you don't need down the line.

Comment: @ramsey-lanier This works great for constructing the route, thank you! What I can't figure out now is the data context of the tagPage pages. Ideally I'd love to be able to use a portion that spit out the tag name for a title section and then looped through the posts in that query passed into data. How would that work? If I use `{{this}}` I get `object Object` and if I use `{{#each posts}} {{title}} {{/each}}` I get nothing.

Comment: technically {{#each this}} {{title}} {{/each}} should work but it isn't very semantic. See, in your new tags template the data context is available as {{thiss} - and in this case, the data context is a cursor (a result of a Collection.find()). So, when you use {{this}} inside of an {{#each}} block, you are saying "for each document returned in the cursor, do whatever is inside this block".